# how to change row Background color in ssrs when all values in a group

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services

I have Column Type and Group MonthNum. How can I change a Background color or each row?
Trying to use SWITCH function but for some reason it doesnt do enything:

```
=SWITCH 
        (
        Fields!Type.Value = "Submitted - New Business" , "LightGrey",
        Fields!Type.Value = "Submitted - Renewals" , "LightGrey",
        Fields!Type.Value = "Submitted - ALL" , "Silver",
        Fields!Type.Value = "Quoted - New Business" , "LightBlue",
        Fields!Type.Value = "Quoted - Renewals" , "LightBlue",
        Fields!Type.Value = "Quoted - ALL" , "LightSteelBlue",
        Fields!Type.Value = "Bound - New Business" , "LightGrey",
        Fields!Type.Value = "Bound - Renewals" , "LightGrey",
        Fields!Type.Value = "Bound - ALL" , "Silver",
        Fields!Type.Value = "Declined - New Business" , "LightBlue",
        Fields!Type.Value = "Declined - Renewals" , "LightBlue",
        Fields!Type.Value = "Declined - ALL" , "LightSteelBlue",

        "Transparent"
        )
```

I need something like that:
[image]

My group:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=SWITCH 
    (
    Fields!Type.Value = "Submitted - New Business" , "LightGrey",
    Fields!Type.Value = "Submitted - Renewals" , "LightGrey",
    Fields!Type.Value = "Submitted - ALL" , "Silver",
    Fields!Type.Value = "Quoted - New Business" , "LightBlue",
    Fields!Type.Value = "Quoted - Renewals" , "LightBlue",
    Fields!Type.Value = "Quoted - ALL" , "LightSteelBlue",
    Fields!Type.Value = "Bound - New Business" , "LightGrey",
    Fields!Type.Value = "Bound - Renewals" , "LightGrey",
    Fields!Type.Value = "Bound - ALL" , "Silver",
    Fields!Type.Value = "Declined - New Business" , "LightBlue",
    Fields!Type.Value = "Declined - Renewals" , "LightBlue",
    Fields!Type.Value = "Declined - ALL" , "LightSteelBlue",
    true, "Transparent"
    )
```

Or change "transparent" to "white", which works better with some output formats. Also, Make sure the field values don't have weird spaces or characters, like "Quoted - ALL " (space after "ALL"). That will mess up the equivalency test.

Comment: AWESOME!!! It works, Thank you very much. 
So, what this `true` statement means in this context?

Comment: Glad to help! SWITCH will stop at the first thing that evaluates to true, so the last statement is basically "if true is true, use transparent". Just make sure the default is at the end!